# How to sort an array of numbers which has separator in between?

Tags: php

I have an array of numbers each with numbers in both side but a separator between both numbers.For example:

```
$selectTableRows= array("1_6", "3_4", "10_1", "2_2", "5_7");
```

I need to sort the array depending on the numbers **after** the separator "_".Thus, the result should be like,

10_**1** , 2_**2**  , 3_**4** , 1_**6** , 5_**7**

Need help in php.

Thank You

Comment: Why is the most significant number at the end? If you swap them you can use `natsort`. If you want to sort only on the last number write a custom sort function using `usort` and `explode`.

Comment: That's not an array of numbers; numbers don't appear between quotes and have a separator. That's an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `usort` and `explode` functions:

```
$selectTableRows = array("1_6", "3_4", "10_1", "2_2", "5_7");
usort($selectTableRows, function ($a, $b){
    return explode('_', $a)[1] - explode('_', $b)[1];
});

print_r($selectTableRows);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10_1
    [1] => 2_2
    [2] => 3_4
    [3] => 1_6
    [4] => 5_7
)
```